# Groupby Python Pandas function in Power BI is showing only values

Tags: python, powerbi

I have about 10 million rows and trying to groupby my data in Power BI by several columns. I've  tried to do this with Power Query editor with "Group By" button but the performance is taking about 15-20 minuts. Then to boost the performance I've tried Python Pandas `groupby` function but the result is showing only VALUES.
My script is: `data = data.groupby(['date', 'client ', 'product'] ).sum()`

**Input data**

`date`   `client`   `product` `qty`   `total amount`  
`07-05-2022`  `Client-1` `Phone`   `5`      `5000`          
`07-05-2022`  `Client-2` `PC`      `8`      `8500`          
`07-05-2022`  `Client-2` `PC`      `8`      `8500`

**Output data**

`qty`    `total amount` 
`5`       `5000`         
`16`      `17000`

as you can see groupby with python function is not working as expected.
Could someone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want something like this ?

```
data = data.groupby(["date", "client", "product"], as_index=False).sum()
print(data)

         date    client product  qty  totalamount
0  07-05-2022  Client-1   Phone    5         5000
1  07-05-2022  Client-2      PC   16        17000
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['07-05-2022','07-05-2022','07-05-2022'],
                   'client':['Client-1','Client-2','Client-2'],
                   'product':['Phone','PC','PC'],
                  'qty':[5,8,8],
                  'total amount': [5000,8500,8500]})
```

The key is to add `as_index=False` arguement to `groupby`

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['date', 'client', 'product'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Here is the result

```
    date        client      product  qty    total amount
0  07-05-2022   Client-1    Phone     5        5000
1  07-05-2022   Client-2    PC        16      17000
```